# How to read XML file into two dimensional array using Java

Tags: java, xml

How to read XML file into two dimensional array using java. I am new to this concept. Please suggest to me any ideas and suggest any websites and examples regarding this question.

My 2-D xml file will look like this:

```
<Base>
    <Map>
        <Display>0B85</Display>
        <Keys>61</Keys>
    </Map>
    <Map>
        <Display>0B86</Display>
        <Keys>62</Keys>
    </Map>
</Base>
```

I want to read this xml file into a two-dimensional array. Suppose I have an array xml[10][40]. In this array I want to display as xml[0][0]=character and xml[0][1]=keys using java program. Please suggest any idea.

Comment: Urgency won't speed up the answer; a clear problem statement will. This question is too broad and vague. What kind of data is in the XML? How should appear in the array? Have you tried anything at all yourself? Show some code if you have.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading it into a map. Use the [DocumentBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) API:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse( new File(fileName) );
```

You can then use the DocumentBuilder's methods to grab the data as required, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("NameOfTag");
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this and managed to do it here, in [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/djangofan/testng-dataprovider-xstream-xml).   Basically, I use [XStream API](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to create a DataProvider for TestNG tests.  It reads data into a 2-D object array.